# Shift and Sort the Sequence

Tags: mathematics, algorithm, sequence

Given a permutation of integers 1 through N, we need to determine whether it is possible to sort this list in an increasing order by following certain conditions.

The conditions imposed are : 
We are allowed to perform the following type of operation upto K times :

- Choose three pairwise distinct indices i<sub>1</sub>, i<sub>2</sub>, i<sub>3</sub> in any order. Note that these indices need not necessarily be chosen in increasing order.

  Perform a cyclic right shift on the elements at these indices i. e. 
   if we denote the values of pi<sub>1</sub>, pi<sub>2</sub> and pi<sub>3</sub> before this operation by v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub> and v<sub>3</sub> respectively, we should
  change pi<sub>2</sub> to v<sub>1</sub>, pi<sub>3</sub> to v<sub>2</sub> and pi<sub>1</sub> to v<sub>3</sub>

For example, the permutation (1,4,3,2,5) can be changed to the permutation (1,5,3,4,2) in one operation by choosing i<sub>1</sub> = 2, i<sub>2</sub> = 4 and i<sub>3</sub> = 5

If it is possible to sort the given permutation we should also display the number of operations along with the indices i<sub>1</sub>, i<sub>2</sub>, i<sub>3</sub> at which the operation is performed

For example
N = 4 
K = 2 
Sequence : 3 2 4 1

Output 
No. of operations performed = 1 
Sequence of indices for each operation: 
1 3 4

Explanation 
We can sort the permutation by performing one cyclic right shift operation on the indices 1, 3 and 4

Comment: This looks like a problem from a programming competition. Do you have the source?

Answer (score 1):

1. I agree with Dmitry Kamenetsky that this looks like a programming competition, so I won't at this time give algorithms, just results.
2. Fully $\frac{1}{2}$ of the possible input have no solution.
3. The longest optimal solution for $N$ integers is of length $\big\lfloor{\frac{N}{2}}\big\rfloor$.
4. The bit about a cyclic right shift is deceptive.  You can do both directions just by swapping $i_2$ and $i_3$.

Comment: A basic sketch of an algorithm would be appreciated.

Comment: Specifically, right-shifting triplets is an even permutation, so only even permutations can be sorted.

Comment: @JasonTodd   But you need to tell us where this came from.  We don't help in active competitions.  That's the rule here.